# Retrofit request body: Required fields

Tags: java, retrofit, retrofit2

The process of using a request body is described in the official API Declaration page as such:

```
@POST("users/new")
Call<User> createUser(@Body User user);
```

While there is no guide for creating the User object, I imagine it can look something like this:

```
public class User {
    public String name;
    public String group;
}
```

By extension, this would result in a request body like this:

```
{ 
    "name": string, 
    "group": string 
}
```

By default, these fields seem to be optional. What is the best way I can make them required?

Comment: You seem not to need it: let your server decide if your request body is valid or not.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv So the best way is to validate manually? I was hoping for a more intuitive way that resembles the validation that query parameters have, for instance `javax.validation.constraints @NotNull`

Comment: I mean send the request as-is, and let the server accept or reject itself. Or is there any solid reason why you need to do it at the client side?

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv Thank you so much for your extensive answer. I am only interested in a server side solution, I apologize if I was unclear. I am using the `@NotNull` annotation in my request classes on path parameters, but since that doesn't work for body fields I was wondering if there was a similar solution. From what I can gather from your answer, the closest solution would be to implement validation rules during the request handling. Is this a fair assumption?

Comment: Sorry can't parse your question, but it sounds like you can find the answer in my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways of accomplishing such a behavior. You can:

- ... validate your objects to be `POST`ed before you invoke a Retrofitted-service (user input forms, etc), and let it fail fast.
- ... validate your *domain* objects, centralized, in a Retrofit request converter and use chained converters
- ... validate your *data transfer objects* objects (if you have any), centralized, after they are converted from *domain* objects and prepared to be sent
- ... rely on the server API implementation and don't care for validation at the client side: no need to duplicate server logic ad-hoc, you may run out sync with the server API validation, you write more code, etc. This is what I was suggesting you in that comment.

If you **really** need to validate the request bodies before they are sent, you should go with the first option. If you want to make the validation fully centralized, you can implement a custom Retrofit converter to make pre-validation on fly. (The code below uses Java 8 and a little bit of Google Guava, Retrofit 2 and Gson, however it can be easily reworked for another components).

Consider these:

```java
interface IService {

    @POST("/")
    Call<String> post(
            @Body User user
    );

}
```

```java
final class User {

    final String name;
    final String group;

    User(final String name, final String group) {
        this.name = name;
        this.group = group;
    }

}
```

Now we can implement Retrofit-stuff. The following `mockOkHttpClient` is a mock `OkHttpClient` to consume any request and respond with `HTTP 200 OK` and `"OK"`.

```java
private static final OkHttpClient mockOkHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(chain -> new Response.Builder()
                .request(chain.request())
                .protocol(HTTP_1_0)
                .code(HTTP_OK)
                .body(ResponseBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), "\"OK\""))
                .build()
        )
        .build();
```

Now let's make a simple test:

```java
final Iterable<Retrofit> retrofits = ImmutableList.of(
        getAsIsRetrofit(),
        getValidatedDomainObjectsRetrofit(),
        getValidatedDataTransferObjectsRetrofit()
);
final User user = new User("user", "group");
for ( final Retrofit retrofit : retrofits ) {
    final IService service = retrofit.create(IService.class);
    final String message = service.post(user).execute().body();
    System.out.println(message);
}
```

As you can see, there are three Retrofit instances that are instantiated with different configurations to demonstrate each of them.

The following `Retrofit` instance does not care the validation itself. And this is another time I recommend you to go with: simply post what you get as is and let the server API implementation deal with it itself. Consider the API implementation to return nice responses like `HTTP 400 Bad Request`, etc.

```java
private static Retrofit getAsIsRetrofit() {
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(mockOkHttpClient)
            .baseUrl("http://whatever")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}
```

The following `Retrofit` instance validates the given `User` object *before* it's converted to a Gson-friendly representation (depends on if you have *domain objects to data transfer object transformations* in your application):

```java
private static Retrofit getValidatedDomainObjectsRetrofit() {
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(mockOkHttpClient)
            .baseUrl("http://whatever")
            .addConverterFactory(new Converter.Factory() {
                @Override
                public Converter<?, RequestBody> requestBodyConverter(final Type type, final Annotation[] parameterAnnotations,
                        final Annotation[] methodAnnotations, final Retrofit retrofit) {
                    if ( type != User.class ) {
                        return null;
                    }
                    final Converter<Object, RequestBody> nextConverter = retrofit.nextRequestBodyConverter(this, type, parameterAnnotations, methodAnnotations);
                    return (Converter<Object, RequestBody>) value -> {
                        if ( value instanceof User ) {
                            final User user = (User) value;
                            requireNonNull(user.name, "name must not be null");
                            requireNonNull(user.group, "group must not be null");
                        }
                        return nextConverter.convert(value);
                    };
                }

            })
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}
```

And the next one validates *data transfer objects* before they are written to output streams. Probably the most low-level instance here.

```java
private static Retrofit getValidatedDataTransferObjectsRetrofit() {
    final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new TypeAdapterFactory() {
                @Override
                public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
                    if ( typeToken.getRawType() != User.class ) {
                        return null;
                    }
                    final TypeAdapter<T> delegateTypeAdapter = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, typeToken);
                    return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
                        @Override
                        public void write(final JsonWriter out, final T value)
                                throws IOException {
                            if ( value instanceof User ) {
                                final User user = (User) value;
                                requireNonNull(user.name, "name must not be null");
                                requireNonNull(user.group, "group must not be null");
                            }
                            delegateTypeAdapter.write(out, value);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public T read(final JsonReader in)
                                throws IOException {
                            return delegateTypeAdapter.read(in);
                        }
                    };
                }
            })
            .create();
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(mockOkHttpClient)
            .baseUrl("http://whatever")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();
}
```

Note that `requireNonNull` is a JDK 8 method, and if you want something like `@NotNull`, you can implement your own annotation processor, or find such an implementation in the Internet considering my implementation idea useless. :) However, I think you'd like the as-is approach the most.